# What to do? .htacces or something else?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I don't really know how to describe my problem properly, but anyway, here goes: 
What I want to to is prevent some of my url from changing when linking between pages.

Fx:

```
localhost/intro/index.php
```

Now the "index.php" part is what I want to rename, or hide, throughout all of my pages, if possible.

An example of what I want to do:

```
www.cvkweb.dk/wi/doku.php
```

Try clicking at some of the green links at the page, and you'll notice that the "doku.php" part in the url doesen't change..

But how do I do it? .htacces?

Thank y'all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shown example, they don't change the requested page, because they use one and the same page... Imagine this kind of structure and code:

**index.php**

```
<p>Hello world</p>
<a href="index.php?id=1">Go to 1</a>
<a href="index.php?id=2">Go to 2</a> <!-- all the anchors are referring to self -->

<?php if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == '1'): ?>
    <p> You have opened link number one </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == '2'): ?>
    <p> You have opened link number two </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Conditionally by what is requested via the querystring, the response is controlled.

Which I would tell is bad practice, and you will end up with one single page which is full of code. Even if you do includes, and so on.

You way to go might be url rewritting, but not the way you wanted, but some routing which will map certain words from the url to certain pages. However, it will be not so hard to reverse what `site.com/page/id` is referring to `page.php?id=1`

So completely not knowing what is the requested page to the end user is nearly impossible. I would suggest to drop this desire. And maybe google about single page applications

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to touch the server configuration.

Just link to the URL you want to link to.

Then write code in `index.php` to read [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and return different content based on the values of your query string.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewriting can't help you there. The browser will always display the URL of the page you're currently on in the address bar. Your server will return data based on the requested URL. Therefore: page == URL. You can't display different pages with identical URLs.

However, you can change the content of a page client side without needing to load a new page. This can be done by embedding HTML frames/iframes in the page, or by using Javascript to get content from different URLs and placing it in the current page.

The page in your example links to completely different URLs, it distinguishes pages based on the query parameter (`?...`). That's a different URL. The PHP script returns different content based on it. No URL rewriting involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `$_GET`  method.
[PHP $_GET Method](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/reserved.variables.get.php)

You can pass a parameter via `URL` and based on what parameter you pass, display a certain content.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confused. 1Index.php` is a special case - it's usually defined as an option in the DirectoryIndex config on an Apache installation. But you are not asking about index.php. You don't say what webserver you are using. Looking at the page you linked, it is clearly a Dokuwiki installation.

There are very detailled instructions on how to implement URL re-writing [in the Dokuwiki manual](https://www.dokuwiki.org/rewrite)